# Nativescript Carousel - show bit of prev and next slides

Tags: nativescript, carousel, nativescript-angular

I'm using NativeScript plugin carousel to get carousel in my app.
[nativescript-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-carousel)

I need to show bit of previous and next slides so that user can know there is more slides exist.
I checked issues on its GitHub repo. I can not set width to a slide as default it'll take 100% off the screen. Can anyone suggest an alternate way or plugin for this, for NativeScript?

version info- package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "nativescript-angular": "^8.2.2",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^6.1.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.3.0"
}
```

Comment: I don't think that plugin has the option out of the box. You may try [nativescript-pager](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-pager) Or [nativescript-carousel-view](https://github.com/alexrainman/nativescript-carousel-view).

Comment: @Manoj Thanks manoj. Neither of this are useful for my case. I either have to change functionality to scroll and tap, to get things done, or provide a toast when user loads the page to indicate there are swipable cards in here. :)

Comment: So in that case you will have to implement pagesCount feature in the plugin you are using, refer the original code in nativescript-pager and you could do similar.